# How to create custom error_php file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

Searching for the solution to style the custom "A PHP Error" message, for 404 we can override but what about the php error and db error. While styling the error_db its worked but not worked with `error_php` in `views/error`

Comment: Why do you want to style? It's not recommend to show these errors in production. It's better to log them and only show simple message "Something went wrong" to the user.

Comment: In error messages it show full file path that will helps users to identify i'm using codeigniter so i'm trying to hide the file path and show custom style for error.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but is it relevant for the user to know if it's a php error, db error? I suppose to separate things as 401, 403, 404, 500 but with no information for the user. But log the full error to your log system.

Comment: Then what about the hackers? is it safe to show the full path?

Comment: No, sure not ;-) You need to set the right environment. You're in test or dev mode now. Please set to production. In your `index.php`, this line: `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` In this environment, there's no critical information for hackers.

Comment: @schellingerht Thank you..

Comment: Shibin, you're welcome. Please mark the right answer, so other users can use it too ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These information is shown because your environment is in development mode.

For production, set in your `index.php` the following:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

So you provide minimal information to the user and no critical information to the hacker.

It's important to **log** the errors, so set in your `config.php`:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4; // or less information by decreasing the number.
```

There are more options for debugging. For example `db_debug`. See for more information https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: now works perfectly but now showing " currently unable to handle this request." for error how to show corresponding error message?

Comment: Could you check your error log? In the first place it's crucial to solve possible issues if there are scenario's your code gives an error. Secondly, the production environment with minimal information but maximal logs are useful for production, not for your development environment. Thirdly, I suppose this is an 500 error, which you can find in the `errors` view directory